# Registry command to open url with default browser for files with a specific extension

Tags: batch-file, registry

I have a request to open a certain file extension, e.g. `.mylog` in a local url and pass the file path.

My first implementation is using batch file:

**test.bat:**

```
start "" http://localhost:3210/?myFile=%1
```

Then on a file I set *Open with test.bat* which then launches browser with `http://localhost:3210/?myFile=C:\currentFile.mylog`

I am trying to do that with registry without the middle step to link to batch file.

In registry (open command for .mylog) I can set:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://localhost:3210/?myFile=%1
```

and this works, launches Chrome with correct url.

Problem is that I cannot limit users to Chrome, need to launch the default browser.

Is there a way to do this in registry like it is possible with **start** command in batch?

Comment: Would `test.bat` not automatically use the default browser? _or technically the program set as the default for http_.

Comment: Yes, `test.bat` launches the default browser. I am trying now to implement it to work that way with only with registry command but cannot find a way.

Comment: `cmd /c start http://localhost:3210/?myFile=%1` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @DavidPostill

```
cmd /c start http://localhost:3210/?myFile=%1
```

**works** and is exactly what is needed!